# VBA Run Add-in from ribbon

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I wrote an excel add-in and have a userform with two buttons: Ok and Cancel. On "Ok", my macros are called and will run. On cancel, it will close the userform.

My question: How do I make the add-in appear on the Add-in Toolbar in excel, and will my userform automatically activate when the add-in is clicked?

Thank you!

Comment: what sort of excel add-in are we talking about here? XML using CustomUI or C#?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, I am fairly new to this sort of thing, but I wrote the macros and add-in using VBA, and saved the file as .xlam

Comment: oh like a personal workbook?

Comment: Yes, but I would like it to be available to any workbook. The macro is written so it runs pertaining to the open workbook, but I'd like it to be as if on the Add-in toolbar my add-in was listed and I can click it to run, and the userform will automatically activate when it runs.

Comment: @art123456 Here's a detail walkthrough on how to create ribbon using CustomUI: http://erpcoder.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/how-to-create-a-custom-ribbon-addin-for-excel-2010/

Comment: Thank you Alex, but is this the only way to get a created add-in onto the toolbar? I feel this is a lengthy process but it should be easier?

Comment: If you just want a button on the Add-ins tab, you can still use the old CommandBars code as in previous versions of Excel.

Comment: Rory, this sounds like what I'm looking for, can you elaborate on how to use this?

Comment: @Rory Sorry, I forgot to tag you in my comment above

Comment: @art123456 I've added some sample code as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the old commandbars code, it can be as simple as this for example:

```
Sub AddButton()
    Dim btn As CommandBarButton
    DeleteButton
    Set btn = Application.CommandBars(1).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With btn
        .Caption = "some text"
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!macro_name"
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
        .Tag = "MyTag"
    End With
End Sub
Sub DeleteButton()
    Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars(1).Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "MyTag" Then ctl.Delete
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

call AddButton from the Workbook_Open event and make sure to clean up in Workbook_BeforeClose. ;) So in the ThisWorkbook module of your add-in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
AddButton
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
DeleteButton
End Sub
```

Comment: Rory, this is awesome, thank you! Just a couple questions though. So I will have to change `ThisWorkbook.Name` and `!macro_name` to the workbook my addin is saved to as well as the macro i'd like it to run on startup, correct? I am also unsure of what `MyTag` represents. Thanks again for this, it's a huge help :)

Comment: Or actually, this is written in a module of the current workbook, so I will just have to change the `macro_name`, right?

Comment: Yes, just change the macro_name part. The "MyTag" is just a means of identifying any controls you create so they can be deleted later.

Comment: So I added this code to a new module in my add-in, but it does not yet bring up a button on the toolbar to run the add-in. Is there a certain way to load it?

Comment: You need to call it from the Open event in the ThisWorkbook module. I'll add something to the answer.

Comment: So I placed the code into the ThisWorkbook module but I'm getting the error: `Object doesn't support this property or method` at the `For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars(1)` line

Comment: Apologies - missed the `.Controls` off the end of that line. I've just amended the code.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered how to do this a few days ago!

1. [Download the openxml editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx)
2. From the editor, Open the file with the macro you want to convert to addin
   3  Insert Custom UI Part, choose the Excel 2007 option.
3. Click on the type and write this code:

   http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui'>

with imageMso you can choose the image of your button. [You can see all the images available](http://imagemso.codeplex.com/downloads/get/769186).

1. Click Validate and then Generate Callback. Copy the Callback code. It will look something like

   'Callback for Button1 onAction
   Sub callMyMacro(control As IRibbonControl)
   End Sub
2. Save the editions in the UI Editor and close.
3. Now open the file with the macro, insert a new module and paste the Callback code. In the middle of the sub, make a call to your macro.

   'Callback for Button1 onAction
   Sub callValidation(control As IRibbonControl)
       Call myMacro
   End Sub
4. By now you should be able to see your macros in the addins tab. Save the file as an AddIn and you're ready.